# Multi resolution is not working in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, screen-resolution

I am trying to run my app for different resolution windows phones. I have taken help from
 [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Multi_resolution)

This is my Code

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Net;
     using System.Windows;
     using System.Windows.Controls;
     using System.Windows.Navigation;
     using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
     using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
     using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
     using reso.Resources;

     namespace reso
     {
         public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
         {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Image myImage = new Image();

        if (MultiRes.Is720p)
            myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("overlay_480x853.png"));
        else if (MultiRes.IsWvga)
            myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("background.png"));
        else if (MultiRes.IsWxga)
            myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("background.png"));


    }



    private void MutliRes_ScreenSize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "ActualHeight: " + Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight + Environment.NewLine +
            "ActualWidth: " + Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth + Environment.NewLine +
            "ScaleFactor : " + Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor + Environment.NewLine);
    }



    private void MultiRes_Resolution(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "IsHD: " + MultiRes.IsHighResolution + Environment.NewLine +
            "Resolution: " + MultiRes.CurrentResolution);
    }

    public static class MultiRes
    {
        public static bool IsHighResolution
        {
            get { return Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor > 100; }
        }

        public static bool IsLowResolution
        {
            get { return Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor <= 100; }
        }

        public static bool IsWvga
        {
            get
            {
                return Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight == 800
                    && Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 100;
            }
        }

        public static bool IsWxga
        {
            get { return Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 160; }
        }

        public static bool Is720p
        {
            get { return Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 150; }
        }

        public static String CurrentResolution
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsWvga) return "WVGA";
                else if (IsWxga) return "WXGA";
                else if (Is720p) return "HD720p";
                else throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown resolution");
            }
        }
    }




}
```

}

but it is giving error 'System.UriFormatException' in

```
          myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("background.png"));
```

I am not able to get what exatly is wrong, i am new to windows app development so please help me out to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 2 parameters, while you initializes a new instance of the Uri class .

```
new Uri("background.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

Next step is to add image to the project.

[image]

Image Path:

```
Assets/background.png
```

The last step is to add image to the View.

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myImage);
```

---

```
        Image myImage = new Image();

        myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/background.png", UriKind.Relative));

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myImage);
```

Comment: I  tried this, error was removed but no image was coming

Comment: @zap92 What is the image PATH?

Comment: C:/Users/Rupak/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/reso/reso/background.png

Comment: @zap92 I’m glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Always check that the `Build Action` Property in the Image is set to `Content`